# need to re-wrap text in webview when zooming

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using android **webview** to show an article .
I need to re-wrap the text whenever the user make a zoom .
I'm using android lollipop .

I found this solution but it is not working for me ?

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
settings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Any trick to do that?
Is there is a way to reload the webview whenever the user make a zoom so it will be loaded wrapped to the new size?

Comment: Hi, pls let us know you fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do that in javascript function and call that through the javascript client of webview.
for details visit:
[android webview basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)